# Variable Assignments in Stylus

Tags: css, meteor, stylus

I am trying to place my variable assignments for media queries in a global.styl file.

The following works if it's in the same file:

`tablet = "all and (max-width: " + 768px+ ")" //variable assignment
 @media tablet {
      text-align: left;
      padding: 122px;
 }`

But if I try to move the variable assignment to global.styl file, it does not work.

I'd like to avoid having to come back and refactor after I figure out why meteor and or stylus is not reading the global variable from another file, so any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Meteor's stylus package compiles each `.styl` file individually. If you want to split a stylesheet into multiple files, you need to use stylus's `@import` directive as normal. Name your imported (globals) file with the extension `.import.styl` and Meteor will only watch it for changes, without trying to compile it by itself.

```
// globals.import.styl
tablet = "all and (max-width: " + 768px+ ")"

// media-queries.import.styl
// ...
@media tablet {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 122px;
}
// ...

// style.styl
@import 'globals.import'
@import 'media-queries.import'
```

By the way, I highly recommend checking out [Rupture](https://github.com/jenius/rupture), which comes packaged with the `cryptoquick:stylus-multi` meteor package.